# Display column names in their original order?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to display column names one at a time in MySQL but the problem is it keeps displaying them in alphabetical order. The syntax I'm using is:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 
'customer_info' and table_name='customer_contact' order by column_name LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;
```

In the `customer_contact` table there are three columns which are `cust_id`, `cust_cell_num` and `cust_email`. When I use the syntax above it displays the `cust_cell_num` instead of `cust_id`.

When changing the syntax to the following:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 
    'customer_info' and table_name='customer_contact' order by column_name LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0;
```

It displays the column names in the following order: `cust_cell_number`, `cust_email`, `cust_id`.

How can I get it to display them in the order they actually appear on the database which is: `cust_id`, `cust_email`, `cust_cell_num`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'customer_info' 
and table_name = 'customer_contact' 
order by ordinal_position
limit 3 offset 0;
```

See official manual here [The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)